# Timer not starting when Called for

Tags: xcode, timer, nstimer, nstimeinterval

Timer is not starting when the button is pressed. I am trying to create an app that whenever a button is pressed the timer starts and at a certain point the timer stops and then picks up where I left off.

```
    -(IBAction)start:(id)sender{
    [self startTimer];

    [self counterStart];

}

- (void)startTimer
{
    homeButton.hidden=YES;
    gameButton.hidden=YES;


    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 20.0f;

    // Create a timer. Adjust the elapsed time.
    if (counter == 0)
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(timeInterval - _elapsedTime)
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
    // Save the start date.
    startDate = [NSDate date];
}


- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    // Clean.
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    _elapsedTime = 0.0;

    [self startTimer];

    // Additional handling.
}


- (void)pauseTimer
{
    // Clean.
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil;

    // Save the elapsed time.
    _elapsedTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and i try to use "timerWithTimeInterval" instead of "scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval", and it start works, try this -

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:(timeInterval - _elapsedTime) target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];
```